# How many URL's for this configuration?

Tags: encoding, url-shortener, base32

I am using yoururls with Base32 encoding to send shortened links within an sms. The URL is preceded by a message and since sms is limited to 160 characters and my messages are approximately 140 characters I need to be very careful about character count.

My question is this; How do I calculate how many URL's I can fit with a 4 character limit using base32 encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are asking about [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Each character in base32 encoding can have 32 values ([A - Z] and [2 - 7]). If you use the form `http://yoursite.com/xxxx`, where `xxxx` is the short URL, four digits can contain 32 <sup>4</sup> permutations. That is, **1,048,576**.

If you also include URLs with three digits (e.g. `http://yoursite.com/xxx`), you can have 32 <sup>3</sup> permutations. That is, **32,768**. Together with four-digit URLS, then you get a total of **1,081,344**.

If you also use 2 digit URLs (e.g. `http://yoursite.com/xx`), you get additional 1,024 URLS, totalling **1,082,368**. And including single digits (e.g. `http://yoursite.com/x`) will give you additional 32. totaling **1,082,400**.

---

But you don't need to use only [A - Z] and [2 - 7]. As per [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), you can use characters `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`. That's 84 different characters. With this:

```
http://yoursite.com/xxxx               49,787,136
http://yoursite.com/xxx added          50,379,840 (+592,704)
http://yoursite.com/xx added           50,386,896 (+  7,056)
http://yoursite.com/x added            50,386,980 (+     84)
```

Even if you leave out characters `-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`, because they would really not fit in a shortened URL, you'll still get 62 characters. With that:

```
http://yoursite.com/xxxx               14,776,336
http://yoursite.com/xxx added          15,014,664 (+238,328)
http://yoursite.com/xx added           15,018,508 (+  3,844)
http://yoursite.com/x added            15,018,570 (+     62)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. It was good except where you stated the part about A-Z being part of base 32. I think you meant a-z. Anyhow, I will award you the bounty as you helped me to understand it.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I decided to go with caps because [RFC4648: The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648) uses capital letters. See table 3 of the RFC.